# MySQL string matching using dashes

Tags: mysql

I am currently migrating data from MySQL 5.6.41 on Windows, to MySQL 8.0.21 on Windows. Overall, a pretty smooth migration, with a couple of very frustrating hiccups. There's one table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
`intDomainID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`txtDomain` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`dtDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`blnTor` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`txtTLD` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`intDomainID`),
UNIQUE KEY `txtDomain` (`txtDomain`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10127897 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The CREATE SCHEMA is complete, and was created by Workbench's "Copy to Clipboard" --> "Create Schema" function.

When I used the built in Workbench export/import, the import always failed with "Duplicate value in txtDomain" (paraphrasing here) error, which is weird because the original table has a UNIQUE KEY constraint on that field, so there cannot be duplicates, and I confirmed, the values it was finding as duplicates were NOT duplicates in the original database.

I then dumped the table using `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, moved the file over to the new server, and did a `LOAD DATE INFILE`. This also failed with the same "Duplicate value in txtDomain" error.

I then removed the UNIQUE KEY constraint, and redid the `LOAD DATE INFILE`. This worked, the data is there. However, I cannot add back the UNIQUE KEY constraint due to "duplicates". I investigated and found this:

Query result on MySQL 5.6.41:
[image: Query result on MySQL 5.6.41]

Query result on MySQL 8.0.21:
[image: Query result on MySQL 8.0.21]

Now, what is going on? The table definition, the database, table and field charset/collations are identical. I need that UNIQUE KEY constraint back...

Why is `http://d­­eepdot35wv­­m­eyd5.onion:80` == `http://d­­ee-p---dot35w-v­­m­eyd5.onion:80`  ??

In case it helps, my export command:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'S:\\temp\\domains.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  FROM domains;
```

My import command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\\DB Backup\\ServerMigration\\domains.txt' 
INTO TABLE domains
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

COLLATIONS:
Collations Old Server: utf8_general_ci [I don't remember touching this value]
New Server: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci [I didn't touch this value]
DB old/new are the same: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
Table old/new are the same: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

This is how the raw TXT file looks like on the file-system:
[image: Some "bad" values in the exported file]

Note, if I paste in one of the URLs from the screenshot into here, it magically turns into the "correct" value, without the dashes:
i.e.:    [http://deepdot35w­­v­­­m­­­eyd5.onion:80](http://deepdot35wvmeyd5.onion:80)

Note2: Using Notepad++, if I convert a regular "dash" to HEX I get "2D". However, if I convert one from the URLs that's causing trouble, I get HEX "C2AD". So it seems that I'm dealing with a weird unicode character and not a dash?

Note3: If anyone wants a small sample file, here it is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ssbl95t2jgn2xy/domains_small.zip

Comment: why didn't you transfer data in the format of SQL script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am aware of the built-in MySQL Workbench "Data Import" and "Data Export" utilities, and that is the first thing I tried. The two databases cannot reach each other due to firewall rules beyond my control.

Comment: try to use SQL as export/import format

Comment: Show a part of `domains.txt` which results shown problematic rows.

Comment: CREATE TABLE is complete. Added COLLATION information to the above post, and also added a section of the domains.txt file.

Comment: what is the characterset?

Comment: Thank you. The problem is a bit clearer now, but I'm still not sure why this discrepancy exists between the two MySQL installations.

Comment: By the way: What you just found is evidence that someone tricked your application into accepting the same domain multiple times. That might be an issue for your business (or might not, depending on what you do). You can avoid that in the future by applying proper **filtering of your user input**.

Comment: Yes, I had realized this issues as well. This data is collected automatically, meaning the URLs came directly from some HTML webpage. I am thinking these "dashes" might be ways of tracking what URL was clicked on. I will have to investigate and clean up the input. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also FYI collation for DB and table cannot be the same on both servers, because `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` didnt exist in 5.6/5.7, it was introduced in 8.0 and thats the culprit of the behaviour difference: a different collation.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you on that. I'm using WorkBench 8 to manage the DB, so maybe that's why, but when I load the "Alter Table" page in WorkBench the collation is clearly showing me "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci". This is the "old DB" for sure.

Comment: The "Table Inspector" shows me a collation of "utf8mb4_general_ci", while the "Alter Table" view shows me "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci". Will have to thank MySQL WorkBench for making things so clear.

Comment: @hades_2100 nevermind. updated the answer to show the actual facts to help others. i can sleep in peace now.  B-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character in question is U+00AD "SOFT HYPHEN" -  a non-printable character that is used to signal a possible hyphenation point inside a word.

It seems that the COLLATION used handles these characters differently on the new setup (MySQL 8.0 with default collation settings) than it did on the old setup (MySQL 5.7 with default collation settings):

These nonprintable characters are now *ignored* in a comparison.

You can test the difference with this simple fiddle. The comparison is "0" in 5.6, but "1" in MySQL 8.0 -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a9bd0bf7de815dc14a886c5069bd1a0f

Note that the SQL fiddle also uses a default collation configuration when it's not specified explicitly.

You might fix that by setting a binary UTF-8 collation for the txtDomain column, which is actually what you want for technical strings anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
  `intDomainID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txtDomain` varchar(100) NOT NULL 
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_binary_ci,
  `dtDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `blnTor` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `txtTLD` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intDomainID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `txtDomain` (`txtDomain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10127897 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**UPDATE:** As it turns out, the COLLATION must have been different between the old (5.6) and new (8.0) setup, as `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` was introduced with MySQL 8.0. The old collation must have been `utf8mb4_general_ci`, which when applied shows the desired behaviour in MySQL 8.0, too.

But still, you should use binary collation for technical strings like URLs anyways.

Comment: Well, that worked! Wow, I did not know this change existed. Thank you VERY much for the help on this!